# Nested loop to add data to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I'm really struggling to comprehend nested for loops and so have done as followed:

```
    int arr[][] = new int[10][3];
    int i, j;

    arr[0][0]=21;  
    arr[1][0]=41;  
    arr[2][0]=61;  
    arr[3][0]=81;  
    etc.
```

... to get the following output:

```
21 21 21
41 41 41
61 61 61
81 81 81
etc.
```

I understand this is highly inefficient, so have attempted to construct a nested for loop which clearly doesn't work:

```
for(i=21;i<81;i+=20)
        {
           for(j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
           {
              arr[i][j] = i+j;
           }
        }
```

A guide in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a nice pair of nested `for` loops to me. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I tried, seem it match with your requirement, you can check it.

```
    int arr[][] = new int[10][3];
    int i, j;
    int value = 21;
    for(i =0; i <10;i++) {
        for(j = 0; j <3; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = value;
        }
        value +=20;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The formula you are interested in seems to be `((i + 1) * 20) + 1` which will give you the value at the correct zero based index. Like,

```
int[][] arr = new int[10][3];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int c = ((i + 1) * 20) + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = c;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Outputs (formatted for post)

```
[[21, 21, 21], [41, 41, 41], [61, 61, 61], [81, 81, 81], 
 [101, 101, 101], [121, 121, 121], [141, 141, 141], 
 [161, 161, 161], [181, 181, 181], [201, 201, 201]]
```

**Note** we could use `Arrays.fill(int[], int)` to fill the array too. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int c = ((i + 1) * 20) + 1;
    Arrays.fill(arr[i], c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might be looking for. Hope it helps

```
int minValue = 21, increment = 20;

int arr[][] = new int[4][3];

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
  {
    arr[i][j] = minValue;
  }
}

minValue += increment;
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `maxValue = 81` ?

Comment: I don't think `j[i].length` in the inner `for` loop will compile.

Comment: Also `i` and `j` are undefined

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Correction has been made to the code.